# How to turn a branded warchief into a bodyguard for another uruk?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I've set up five warchiefs that look how I want them to but after changing my mind I now wish to make four of them the bodyguards of a single warchief, but to do that I need to somehow demote them to captains without killing them so they can then undergo "initiation" to become bodyguards. All of these uruks are branded. Any suggestions on how to do this or another method I could use?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such thing as demotion in Sauron's army. There are only two career paths for an Uruk. Promotion (soldier->captain->bodyguard->warchief) and death.